# Calcular fecha mayor php

Tags: php, date

Estoy realizando un script en el que muestro unas fechas que tengo en un array, a partir de otra fecha dada, tengo que mostrar solamente las fechas mayores o iguales a la fecha dada

Que funciones de php puedo utilizar para el script

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar algo como [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) que devuelve timestamp (número de segundos desde 1970/1/1 hasta ahora) y luego sería simplemente comprobar que entero devuelto es mayor o igual que el que tengas guardado.

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfecto, muchas gracias